# Java Convert to entity from a List<?>

Tags: java, spring, stream

So, i got an method in one class that receives a List of any class (Entity) and i want to map it like:

Class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  

   private int eid;
   private String ename;
   private double salary;
   private String deg;

   public Employee(int eid, String ename, double salary, String deg) {
      super( );
      this.eid = eid;
      this.ename = ename;
      this.salary = salary;
      this.deg = deg;
   }
}
```

List received:

```
0 -> Class reference
```

Map what i want:

```
0 -> List of attributes with their values
```

The thing here is that i don't know what Class is receiving the method.

Comment: And where does the values are supposed to come from ?

Comment: @azro values comes from antopher method that get all the records from db and sav it in the list (List<Entity>).

Comment: This is very unclear^^ try to explain more

Comment: if you have that class reference as a .java file in your project/on classpath, you could use reflection, but this is a very bad aproach and your recieved data should be in a standard format.

Comment: What actually you want from that list? Do you want to convert it into some map?

Comment: @GauravSrivastav I want the attributes and values for each record.

Answer (score 0):

As per your understanding, I think you need a mapper which convert List to entity means you want to convert each object of list to entity.

You can use **ModelMapper** for converting domain/dto to entity object. You can also use Java 8 stream API and map() method to transform your object to desired entity.

```
list.stream()
    .map(Employee::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Define a constructor with dto object as argument as set the fields

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  

   private int eid;
   private String ename;
   private double salary;
   private String deg;

   public Employee(EmployeeDTO dto){
      this.eid = dto.getId();
      ...
   }
   public Employee(int eid, String ename, double salary, String deg) {
      super( );
      this.eid = eid;
      this.ename = ename;
      this.salary = salary;
      this.deg = deg;
   }
}
```

Or Generic Mapper Implementation

```
class BeanMapper{
  ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();//use spring autowiring if use spring
  public static <T,R> R map(T entity,Class targetEntity){
     return mapper.map(entity,targetEntity);
   }
}
```

You **BeanMapper** as like below

```
Employee employee = BeanMapper.map(employeeDto,Employee.class)
```

Comment: The thing is that i dont know if i have to map to an Employee, Person, ...

Comment: In that case you need to implement generic implementation and use ModelMapper library for this. 

class BeanMapper<T,R>{
  
}